# MS Access database issue between different language editions

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

We have a Access DB frontend on which I update functionality on a rolling basis.
Most of the users have Swedish versions of Access including myself. One user runs an English version.

Recently the English version refuses to recognize "Händelseprocedure" as "Event Procedure", rendering the database unuseable.

This seems to be related to this particular frontend, because I can't replicate it on a new frontend, and the older versions of the frontend worked without a problem.

I would appreciate any suggestion as to what the cause of this behaviour might be and any possible fixes.

Thanks in advance //Ot_Gu

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't reproduce the error in a new file, you most likely have a "slightly" corrupt form in your database.  I would recommend trying to `decompile` the database file.

You can get more information about the `/decompile` switch from the following:

[How to Decompile a Database](http://datagnostics.com/dtips/decompile.html)

[Decompile Your Microsoft Access Database](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/Bad_DLL_Calling_Convention.asp)

I would make a backup copy of the database, then do a decompile, and then a compact.  Then open up the database and open your VBA Editor and Compile your code.  Then test under both the Swedish and English versions of Access.

The `/decompile` switch has fixed many strange problems with Microsoft Access databases for me in the past.